# How to write a "GET" Ajax call on clicking a link and render a partial on top a <div>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have defined a new action like this:

```
    def archive
      @archives = current_user.past_appointments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: PAGINATION_PAGES)
    end
```

I have created that link in the navigation bar and on clicking the link I would like to render a partial after doing an ajax call which responds to .js file. 
My div element is having an id="#app_past".
 At first I would like to define my route and how to make that ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Creaste a partial for your past appointments in your views/shared folder, then  you need just a one-line javascript, I assume the controller is `AppointmentsControllers`...

*views/appointments/archives.js.erb*

```
$('#app-past).html('<= escape_javascript(render('shared/past_appointments', archives: @archives)).html_safe %>');
```

Comment: ok, that changes where you store the archives js file. See my edited answer.

Comment: You're welcome. If my reply helped, feel free to accept it by clicking on the option to the left of my reply.  If it didn't, you don't need to. :)